# How does Android creates block devices and mounts it?

Tags: linux, development

How does Android create block devices in `/dev`? Android does not support `devtmpfs` and Android /init does not use udev or (busybox) mdev. **ueventd.rc** doesn't contain strings for `/dev/block/...`.

But, there is one difficult thing. There is many different Android devices and they have got different partitions - by size, type, number of partitions. But `/init` is the same for any device...

Also, I have tried to "trace" ramdisk: I replaced magiskinit with my custom init:

```
 ~ # mkdir ramdisk
 ~ # unmkbootimg boot.img
 ~ # gzip -dc ramdisk.cpio.gz | cpio -i -D ramdisk
 ~ # cd ramdisk
 ~/ramdisk # mv init magiskinit
 ~/ramdisk # mv ../init .
 ~/ramdisk # cat ../src/init.cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/mount.h>
using std::string, std::vector, std::ifstream, std::ofstream, std::ios, std::endl;

int main() {
    string devd;
    mount("proc", "/proc", "proc", 0, NULL);
    vector<string> devblks;
    vector<string> mounts;
    for (auto a : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("/dev")) {
        string pth = (a.path()).c_str();
        devblks.push_back(pth);
    }
    const bool mountext = std::filesystem::exists("/proc/mounts");
    if (mountext) {
        ifstream opn;
        opn.open("/proc/mounts", ios::in);
        while(getline(opn, devd)) {
            mounts.push_back(devd);
        }
        opn.close();
    }
    pid_t parent = fork();
    if (parent) {
        rename("/magiskinit", "/init");
        execlp("/init", "/init", NULL);
    } else {
        while (true) {
            bool ifext = std::filesystem::exists("/data/media/0");
            if (ifext) {
                ofstream output;
                output.open("/data/media/0/sys.log", ios::out);
                for (unsigned int k=0; k < devblks.size(); k++) {
                    output << "Block: " << devblks[k] << endl;
                }
                for (unsigned int j=0; j < mounts.size(); j++) {
                    output << "Mount: " << mounts[j] << endl;
                }
                output.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
// My /init is statically linked binary
```

But my init does not work, it bootloop my device. My device - Android 10 (system-as-root). Maybe it could be work into Android < 10 (ramdisk-as-root devices).

I can't use UART, my device does not support LLCON and FBCON, I can't replace /init with bash shell for checking initramfs))

Also, I can't run it into chroot, it fails:

```
 ~ # chroot android /init
```

And I don't know way to run it on QEMU...

Sorry, but there is too difficult to read source code for me...

I just want to know how Android create blocks, mounts and switch_root to /system without devtmpfs and even without ueventd...

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve? It's more development oriented question. Android's `init`/`ueventd` manages to receive `uevents` from kernel. Block devices are [handled within code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-12.1.0_r1/init/devices.cpp#470) like many other device nodes without relying on `ueventd.rc`.

Comment: Do you want to say that Android init uses `/sys/block/mmcblk0/.../uevent`s for creating block files?

Comment: Android's `init`, `ueventd`, `vold` etc. all listen to kernel's `uevent` notifications over `netlink` socket very much like `udev`.